Inverse of smooth family of diffeomorphisms
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and let $I$ be an open interval. We say a map $\varphi:I \rightarrow \text{Diff}(M)$ is a smooth family of diffeomorphisms if the map $I \times M \rightarrow M$ given by $(t,p) \mapsto \varphi(t)(p)$ is smooth.
Let $\varphi:I \rightarrow \text{Diff}(M)$ be a smooth family of diffeomorphisms, and let $\psi:I \rightarrow \text{Diff}(M)$ be defined by $\psi(t) := \varphi(t)^{-1}$. Does it follow that $\psi$ is a smooth family if diffeomorphisms as defined in the previous paragraph?

Why did my question get downvoted?

Define $\Phi:I\times M\to I\times M$ as $\Phi(t,p)=(t,\phi_t(p))$. This is smooth, bijective with inverse $(t,p)\mapsto (t,\psi_t(p))$. In local coordinates, the derivative of $\Phi$ has the block form
\begin{align}
D\Phi_{(t,p)}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
*&D(\phi_t)_p
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $*$ is irrelevant. The lower right block is invertible since $\phi_t:M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism. Hence, $D\Phi_{(t,p)}$ is invertible. So, by the inverse function theorem, $\Phi$ is a local diffeomorphism. Since $\Phi$ is bijective, it follows that $\Phi$ itself is a diffeomorphism and hence $\Phi^{-1}$ is smooth and so the map $(t,p)\mapsto \psi_t(p)=(\text{pr}_2\circ\Phi^{-1})(t,p)$ is smooth.

This is a very nice answer. Thanks a lot!
